# How to make my windows7 based application run or set notification on windows8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, port

all
I'm working on my windows7 pc with Visual Studio 2013. Windows8 sdk is installed.
I do not want to change a lot to port my project to a windows-store based program but I want my program can send notification while my windows8.1 tablet pc is sleeping.

I don't need my app actually running after entering sleep. I just want to setup an alarm-like (with defined alarming time) notification when I push some button in my app, before entering sleep mode.

Alternatively, I want my app keep playing sound in sleep mode (and the app is still running without rendering)

Is there a workaround without changing too much codes?

P.S. My project uses qt.
P.S.2 I can remote debug on my windows8.1 tablet but it is difficult to code on that tablet..